# Lua: load modules betwen sub-packages

Tags: lua, require, relative-path

I have the following package structure

```
--main.lua
--module1.lua
--utils/
    |----a.lua
    |----b.lua
--data/
    |----c.lua
    |----d.lua
```

from `module1.lua` I know that I can easily call `utils.a` and `data.d` for example. And also that within `utils/a.lua` I can reference `utils/b.lua` by doing something like

```
--a.lua
local current_package = (...):match("(.-)[^%.]+$")
require(current_package .. 'b')
```

But how do I require `utils.a` from `data.c`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
local parent_package = (...):match( "^(.-)[^.]+%.[^.]+$" )
require( parent_package .. "utils.a" )
```

if you think that your given package structure might be part of a bigger package structure. Otherwise you should just use absolute module paths from anywhere:

```
require( "utils.a" )
```

Comment: If `require("utils.a")` works from within `module1.lua` or `main.lua`, it will work from anywhere -- including from within `data/c.lua`, `data/d.lua`, and/or `utils/b.lua`.